# how to make matrix into diagonal matrix in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

given matrix:

```
x = matrix([[ 0.9,  0.14], [ 0.15,  0.8]])
```

how can you make the first column, `x[:,0]`, into a diagonal matrix in numpy? to get:

```
matrix([[0.9, 0],
        [0, 0.15]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
numpy.diag( x.A[ :, 0 ] )
```

should do it.

The difference between a `matrix` and an `array` is crucial here. You won't get the same result from just `numpy.diag( x[ :, 0 ] )`.   `x.A` is a shorthand for `numpy.asarray( x )` when `x` is a `matrix`.

So by the same token, to answer your question precisely I guess I shouldn't forget convert the answer from an `array` back to a `matrix`:

```
numpy.matrix( numpy.diag( x.A[ :, 0 ] ) )
```

Comment: this gives a numpy array back with one element, not a diagonal matrix with zeros

Comment: @user248237dfsf   not for me.  return value is `array([[ 0.9 ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.15]])` .  See edit.  The `.A` is crucial.

Answer (score 3):

There is a `diagflat` that 'Create a two-dimensional array with the flattened input as a diagonal.'.  It both `ravels` the input, and wraps the result in `np.matrix` (matching the input array type):

```
In [122]: np.diagflat(x[:,0])
Out[122]: 
matrix([[ 0.9 ,  0.  ],
        [ 0.  ,  0.15]])
```

So it's doing all the work of `jez` answer, just wrapping it in a generalized function:

```
np.matrix(np.diag(np.asarray(x[:,0]).ravel()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.diag(np.diag(your numpy array))`. E.g.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> b = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)
>>> b
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> np.diag(np.diag(b))
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 5, 0],
       [0, 0, 9]])
```